# How long will I keep getting android updates for nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, stock-android

How long will I get an android update for my nexus  5 device? I purchased this in December 2013 and currently running Marshmallow.

Comment: A Nexus Device has a supported lifetime officially of 2 major version releases of Android over its original version. So Marshmallow will be the last official update you get. However, custom ROMs are a different story. If you go down that road, you could probable have Android O or P before you get completely outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google's update policy for Nexus devices](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705?rd=1):

> Security patches
>
> Nexus devices will also receive updates for security issues documented
>   in our Public Nexus Security Bulletins for at least the following
>   periods:
>
> - Three years from when the device first became available on the Google
>     Store
> - Or, 18 months after the device stopped being sold on the Google
>     Store